# Unable to Stop Custom Service through Cloudera Manager

Tags: cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I have build a custom service. I am doing some pre task (installation of drivers, start database  and other daemon services etc) before calling exec.This service started succefully.
Duing stop from Cloudera Manager , along with the service started with exec I wanto stop the services started in pre task also.for that .I have written a script to stop all the daemon services 
But I found that the only the  service which is started with exec  stops not in the pre-task.

Please Guide me , how to solve the isuue.

My service.sdl is as follows

```
    {
  "name" : "MYAPP",
  "label" : "Myapp",
  "description" : "My App Custom CSD",
  "version" : "2.1",
 "runAs" : {
    "user" : "root",
    "group" : "root"
   },
 "maxInstances" : 1,
 "icon" : "images/myapp.png",

  "parcel" : {
        "repoUrl" : "http://54.12.197.150:8111/latest/",
        "requiredTags" : [ "myapp" ]
 },
   "roles" : [
    {
       "name" : "MY_WEBSERVER",
       "label" : "My Web Server",
       "pluralLabel" : "My Web Server",
       "startRunner" :
        {
         "program" : "scripts/control.sh",
         "args" : [ "start" ]
        },
      "stopRunner" :
        {
                "relevantRoleTypes" : ["MY_WEBSERVER"],
                "runner" :
                {
                "program" : "scripts/control.sh",
                "args" : ["stop"]
                },
                "timeout" : 180000,
                "masterRole" : "MY_WEBSERVER"
        },

        "topology" :
        {
                "minInstances" : "1",
                "maxInstances" : "1"
        },
        "logging" :
        {
                "dir" : "/var/log/myapp-2.1/",
                "filename" : "myapp.log"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

and my control.sh is as follows-

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD=$1

case $CMD in
  (start)
    echo "Starting the MyAPP Service"

        cp -r  /opt/cloudera/parcels/myapp-2.1 /opt/

        chmod 777 -R /opt/myapp-2.1/
        sh /opt/myapp-2.1/resource/scripts/installer/MainScript
        exec python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
        ;;
  (stop)
    sh /opt/myapp-2.1/resource/scripts/installer/StopAll
    ;;
  (restart)
    sh /opt/myapp-2.1/resource/scripts/installer/RestartAll
    ;;

  (*)
        echo "Don't understand [$CMD]"
        ;;
esac
```